# What is the meaning of this value '\x01'?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I `NSLog` `self.isViewLoaded` and it prints `'\x01'` what does it means? I was thinking of a `BOOL` return.

I want to check whether my view is already loaded (I want  to know if `viewWillAppear:` call again) so I checked it like this,

```
if(self.isViewLoaded && self.window.view) {
    //... do something
}
```

but I'm not able to check it, any suggestion with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you do not use the right format specifier in NSLog's string.

Anyway: they clearest form of printing bools IMO is something like

```
NSLog(@"isLoaded: %@", (self.isViewLoaded)? @"YES" : @"NO");
```